# extending a resource endpoint with extra data?

Tags: api, rest, api-design

Is it generally a bad idea to optionally extend a resource endpoint with additional data pertaining to the requested resource?

### Example

`GET /post/:id/` - retrieve a single post

#### Example Response

```
{
 id : 1
 title : 'Hello world',
 body : 'Testing'
}
```

`GET /post/:id/?includeMeta=1` - retrive a single post with additional meta data

#### Example Response

```
{
 id : 1
 title : 'Hello world',
 body : 'Testing',
 meta : {
     url : 'http://google.com',
     customMetaKey : 'some value'
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether these extra values belong to the main resource or not. In your case, if they belong to the resource named "Post" then it's perfectly acceptable. In fact, you can use an approach named "Partial Responses", that was first used by Google. In this case, you have to add a special QueryString attribute named "fields" like the example below.

```
GET /post/:id/?fields=metadata,field2,field3,association(field1,field2)
```

In this queryString you can add all fields you want returned in the response, including the associations. Take a look at the article below to learn more about Partial Responses:

- http://googlecode.blogspot.com.br/2010/03/making-apis-faster-introducing-partial.html

In the other hand, if these extra values don't belong to the main resource then I think it doesn't make any sense. If a client wants those values then it has to ask it to the resource that owns it.